# Spring Batch: Repository changes not committing

Tags: spring-batch

I've got a problem with my spring batch configuration using a RepositoryItemReader, A custom processor and a RepositoryItemWriter to save all the changes back in the Database. I googled my hands off and can't really find an answer or see where the problem is :(

My Job definition is:

```
@NonNull
@Autowired
private MailRepository repository; //data jpa with hibernate and mssql

@Bean
Job sendMailJob(JobExecutionListener jobCompletionListener) { 
    return getJobBuilderFactory().get("sendMailJob")
            .incrementer(new TimeStampIncrementer())
            .listener(jobCompletionListener)
            .flow(sendMailStep1())
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
Step sendMailStep1() {
    return getStepBuilderFactory()
            .get("sendMailStep1").allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .<Mail, Mail> chunk(MAIL_MAX_COUNT)
            .reader(mailReader())
            .processor(sendMailProcessor())
            .writer(mailWriter())
            .build();
}

@Bean
ItemReader<Mail> mailReader() {
    RepositoryItemReader<Mail> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
    reader.setRepository(getRepository());
    reader.setPageSize(MAIL_MAX_COUNT);
    reader.setMaxItemCount(MAIL_MAX_COUNT);
    reader.setMethodName(MailRepository.SEND_BATCH_METHOD_NAME);
    reader.setArguments(Arrays.asList(MailStatus.OPEN));

    Map<String, Direction> sorting = new HashMap<>();
    sorting.put("created", Direction.DESC);
    reader.setSort(sorting);

    return reader;
}

@Bean
ItemProcessor<Mail ,Mail> sendMailProcessor() {
    return new ItemProcessor<Mail, Mail>() {
        @Override
        public Mail process(Mail mail) throws Exception {
            try {
                sendMail(mail);
                mail.setSent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mail.setFailed();
            }
            return mail;
        }
    };
}

@Bean
ItemWriter<Mail> mailWriter() {
    RepositoryItemWriter<Mail> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
    writer.setRepository(getRepository());
    writer.setMethodName("save");
    return writer;
}
```

There's nothing really special about this code: Mails having the status "OPEN" will be read, sent by the processor which also changes the status and these changes should be written back to the repository with the writer using save.

When I debug, the reading, sending and changing the status (not in db) works fine, but all these changes won't be persisted in db after the writer is calling save. The used PlatformTransactionManager seems to be fine, pointing at the correct DataSource and using the right TransactionMode. All changes made internally in the batch-repository (same db) will be written correctly, but none of my changes in the Mail-Entities.
I also got these problem in other batches that are only reading and deleting expired entities. Reading works fine, but no entity is getting deleted. So it seems that the transaction is used by the repository not getting committed. There is no exception; @EnableBatchProcessing is set in the application class.

Has anybody faced the same problem or could help me out?

Thanks for your advice!
Denis

### Debug output:

```
o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=1
o.s.b.item.data.RepositoryItemReader     : Reading page 0
o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Opening JPA EntityManager
o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
o.h.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl       : Rendered criteria query -> select count(generatedAlias0) from Mail as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.status=:param0
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(mail0_.id) as col_0_0_ from mail mail0_ where mail0_.status=?
Hibernate: select count(mail0_.id) as col_0_0_ from mail mail0_ where mail0_.status=?
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: 
o.h.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl       : Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from Mail as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.status=:param0 order by generatedAlias0.created desc
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select TOP(?) mail0_.id as id1_13_, mail0_.created as created2_13_, mail0_.last_modified as last_mod3_13_, mail0_.charset as charset4_13_, mail0_.sender as sender5_13_, mail0_.message as message6_13_, mail0_.sent as sent7_13_, mail0_.status as status8_13_, mail0_.subject as subject9_13_, mail0_.subtype as subtype10_13_, mail0_.suppress_failure as suppres11_13_ from mail mail0_ where mail0_.status=? order by mail0_.created desc
Hibernate: select TOP(?) mail0_.id as id1_13_, mail0_.created as created2_13_, mail0_.last_modified as last_mod3_13_, mail0_.charset as charset4_13_, mail0_.sender as sender5_13_, mail0_.message as message6_13_, mail0_.sent as sent7_13_, mail0_.status as status8_13_, mail0_.subject as subject9_13_, mail0_.subtype as subtype10_13_, mail0_.suppress_failure as suppres11_13_ from mail mail0_ where mail0_.status=? order by mail0_.created desc
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.some.package.mail.Mail#11]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving associations for [com.some.package.mail.Mail#11]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.some.package.mail.Mail#11]
o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Loading collection: [com.some.package.mail.Mail.to#11]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select to0_.mail_id as mail_id1_16_0_, to0_.mail_to as mail_to2_16_0_ from mail_to to0_ where to0_.mail_id=?
Hibernate: select to0_.mail_id as mail_id1_16_0_, to0_.mail_to as mail_to2_16_0_ from mail_to to0_ where to0_.mail_id=?
o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Preparing collection intializer : [com.some.package.mail.Mail.to#11]
o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections were found in result set for role: com.some.package.mail.Mail.to
o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Collection fully initialized: [com.some.package.mail.Mail.to#11]
o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections initialized for role: com.some.package.mail.Mail.to
o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Done loading collection
stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Loading collection: [com.some.package.mail.Mail.cc#11]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select cc0_.mail_id as mail_id1_15_0_, cc0_.cc as cc2_15_0_ from mail_cc cc0_ where cc0_.mail_id=?
Hibernate: select cc0_.mail_id as mail_id1_15_0_, cc0_.cc as cc2_15_0_ from mail_cc cc0_ where cc0_.mail_id=?
o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Preparing collection intializer : [com.some.package.mail.Mail.cc#11]
o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections were found in result set for role: com.some.package.mail.Mail.cc
o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Collection fully initialized: [com.some.package.mail.Mail.cc#11]
o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections initialized for role: com.some.package.mail.Mail.cc
o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Done loading collection
stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Loading collection: [com.some.package.mail.Mail.bcc#11]
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select bcc0_.mail_id as mail_id1_14_0_, bcc0_.bcc as bcc2_14_0_ from mail_bcc bcc0_ where bcc0_.mail_id=?
Hibernate: select bcc0_.mail_id as mail_id1_14_0_, bcc0_.bcc as bcc2_14_0_ from mail_bcc bcc0_ where bcc0_.mail_id=?
o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Preparing collection intializer : [com.some.package.mail.Mail.bcc#11]
o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #0
e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.some.package.mail.Mail.bcc#11]
o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections were found in result set for role: com.some.package.mail.Mail.bcc
o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : Collection fully initialized: [com.some.package.mail.Mail.bcc#11]
o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections initialized for role: com.some.package.mail.Mail.bcc
o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Done loading collection
o.s.b.item.data.RepositoryItemWriter     : Writing to the repository with 1 items.
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Participating in existing transaction
o.s.b.c.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet   : Inputs not busy, ended: false
o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=1, written=1, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Participating in existing transaction
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=158, version=1, name=sendMailStep1, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=1, filterCount=0, writeCount=1 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Participating in existing transaction
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Initiating transaction commit
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[ConnectionID:10 ClientConnectionId: fe7a8cc9-6dcd-4e4c-95d4-ac426b633feb]]]
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Releasing JDBC Connection [ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[ConnectionID:10 ClientConnectionId: fe7a8cc9-6dcd-4e4c-95d4-ac426b633feb]]] after transaction
o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
enter code here
```

Comment: Are you really sure, that you are using the same datasource instance and not a second instance with the same configuration. From what you write, it looks as if the repository-datasource is not part of the transaction, which would only be possible, if this is not the same datasource that writes jto the batch-repository.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Good point, i only looked at the ds parameters.... I just checked that and the SimpleJobRepository (-> JdbCStepExecutionDao -> jdbcTemplate) and the MailRepository (DataSourceConnectionPool) are both pointing on the same DataSource with the same instance id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I configured 2 entityManagerFactories since i've got 2 data sources and wanted to work with entites and repositories. 
I didn't named the primary one "entityManagerFactory" which made no problems so far. Changing this one to the default name solved my problem - but i wonder why this worked partitially before, without any exception....